# Two plots with and without legend with same inner plot size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots, one with legend and another one without.
The legend should be on the right.
Now I want to have two jpg files and the 'inner' plot (everything except the legend) should have the same size in both plots.
I thought of specifying the legend width with `legend.key.width` and add that width to the argument `width` in ggsave. Here it's 2 inches.

That's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
tb <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 10:1, c = rep(letters[1:2], 5))

plot1 <- 
  ggplot(tb, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_point()

plot1

plot2 <- 
  ggplot(tb, aes(a, b, colour = c)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(2, "in"))

plot3

ggsave("plot1.jpg", plot1, width = 5, height = 5, units = "in")
ggsave("plot2.jpg", plot2, width = 7, height = 5, units = "in")
```

Unfortunately the inner plot in `plot2` is still not that wide than the inner plot in `plot1`.
What I really want are two plots that look exactly the same (except of the colors) that I can 'put the one on top of the other and it seems that there is one plot' but `plot2` should have this legend additionally.
Is there any chance? I've tried quite much and looked at every argument of `theme`. I'm sorry for my strange explanation ...

Comment: Would a solution where both graphs are combined into a single jpg-file be okay? Then you could use `grid_arrange_shared_legend` in the `lemon` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get it, similar to the option proposed by @MrGumble you could glue plots together on top of one another using e.g. `patchwork`. If you prefer separate plots then one option would be to make the first plot with a `color` legend but make all text, colors etc. invisible using `scale_color_manual`, `guide_legend` and `theme`.

**1. Separate plots**

```r
library(tidyverse)
tb <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 10:1, c = rep(letters[1:2], 5))

plot1 <- 
  ggplot(tb, aes(a, b, colour = c)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(color = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep("black", length(unique(tb$c)))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA))) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA), legend.text = element_text(color = NA))

plot1
```

[image]

```r
plot2 <- 
  ggplot(tb, aes(a, b, colour = c)) +
  geom_point()

plot2
```

[image]

**2. Using `patchwork`:**

```r
library(patchwork)

plot1 <- ggplot(tb, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_point()

plot1 / plot2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I like both of your proposals :)